# How to convert a list into a dataframe in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list in R in which the objects have different lengths.

Is there any way to convert this list into a dataframe? Maybe adding zeros in the
shorter length objects.

I would like to be able to display a, b and c as columns and the numbers on the rows.

this is a small example. Later I will have to apply it to a list of 84 objects, each of these will have a long and different length from each other.

[image]

```
prova <- list(a = c(c(1:5), c(2,NaN, 4, 6,7)), b = c(c(6:10), c(NaN ,NaN,  6,7)), 
c=c(c(11:15),c(NaN ,NaN, 7.8,8,5,6,3,NaN)))
Thank you!
```

Answer (score 0):

As the `length` of each element is different, we may need to append `NA` at the end to make the lengths same by assigning the `length` to the `max` length of the list element and then convert to `data.frame`

```
mx <- max(lengths(prova))
data.frame(lapply(prova, `length<-`, mx))
```

-output

```
     a   b    c
1    1   6 11.0
2    2   7 12.0
3    3   8 13.0
4    4   9 14.0
5    5  10 15.0
6    2 NaN  NaN
7  NaN NaN  NaN
8    4   6  7.8
9    6   7  8.0
10   7  NA  5.0
11  NA  NA  6.0
12  NA  NA  3.0
13  NA  NA  NaN
```

Comment: that's great, does it work with large lists too?

Comment: @SalvatoreCinque it should. `lengths` is very efficient

Answer (score 0):

other methods include:

```
do.call(rbind, data.table::transpose(prova))
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    1    6 11.0
 [2,]    2    7 12.0
 [3,]    3    8 13.0
 [4,]    4    9 14.0
 [5,]    5   10 15.0
 [6,]    2  NaN  NaN
 [7,]  NaN  NaN  NaN
 [8,]    4    6  7.8
 [9,]    6    7  8.0
[10,]    7   NA  5.0
[11,]   NA   NA  6.0
[12,]   NA   NA  3.0
[13,]   NA   NA  NaN

t(plyr::rbind.fill.matrix(sapply(prova, t)))
   [,1] [,2] [,3]
1     1    6 11.0
2     2    7 12.0
3     3    8 13.0
4     4    9 14.0
5     5   10 15.0
6     2  NaN  NaN
7   NaN  NaN  NaN
8     4    6  7.8
9     6    7  8.0
10    7   NA  5.0
11   NA   NA  6.0
12   NA   NA  3.0
13   NA   NA  NaN
```